# React Native Firebase (FCM) getToken in MainApplication class

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to React Native. I'm try to get token `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()` inside android MainApplication class and pass a token to 3rd party native library. To build solution like this I need add dependencies to my app/build.gradle `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'` otherwise build will fail. It's ok to add this dependency in native code or there is other way to handle case like this with React Native?